# Calculate the number of loop iterations with varying increment

Tags: algorithm, optimization

```
for (; i < limit; i += x) {
  x += 100;
}
```

Is there is an elegant solution to calculate `i` and `x` without the use of a loop construct?

**My thoughts:**

I can use the popular Gauss summation formula `1+2+3+4+...+n = (n*(n+1))/2` and binary search to reduce the complexity from O(N) to O(log N).

```
Assume i = 0, x = 0 then:
i = 0*100 + 1*100 + 2*100 + 3*100 + ... + (n-1)*100 = ((n-1)*n)/2*100

if (i != 0 && x != 0) then:
i = i + x+0*100 + x+1*100 + x+2*100 + ... + x+(n-1)*100 = i+x*n + ((n-1)*n)/2*100

Thus (i < limit) = (i+x*n+((n-1)*n)/2*100 < limit)
```

Now use some kind of binary search to find the greatest `n` that satisfies the above inequality.

```
if (i < limit)
    for (n = 1; i+x*n+((n-1)*n)/2*100 < limit; n -= j, n += 1)
        for (j = 1; i+x*n+((n-1)*n)/2*100 < limit; n += j, j += j);
```

Now that I found the number of iterations `n` of the initial for loop, `i` and `x` can be calculated using:

```
i += x*n+((n-1)*n)/2*100
x += 100*n
```

Any suggestions? Is there a faster O(1) solution?

**O(1) solution:**

```
const int d = 100;
while (i < limit) { i += x; x += d; }
```

With the help of Daniel's answer here is how to calculate the number of iterations `n` and then `i` and `x` in O(1) steps. `i = i+x*n+((n-1)*n)/2*d` (see above) thus we can now solve:

```
i < limit
= i+x*n+(n*(n+1))/2*d < limit
= d*n^2 + (2*x-d)*n - 2*(limit-i) < 0
```

The above formula is a quadratic inequality and can be solved using the [quadratic formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Quadratic_formula):

```
(-b ± (b^2-4ac)^0.5) / 2a
```

Thus the number of iterations `n` is:

```
a = d
b = 2*x-d
c = -2*(limit-i)
n = ceil((-b + sqrt(b*b-4*a*c)) / (2*a))
```

Now that we found the number of iterations `n` of the initial while (for) loop we can calculate `i` and `x` using the two formulas (see above):

```
i += x*n+((n-1)*n)/2*d
x += d*n
```

I tested these formulas using a simple C program and they give the same results as the while (for) loop.

Comment: If you go back through your previous questions and accept some answers, you'll probably get a better response on this question.

Answer (score 1):

It's a quadratic inequality, so you can solve it in O(1) if you can compute square roots in O(1). Depending on the types of the involved numbers, that may or may not be possible.

If `i >= limit` at the beginning, you trivially have no iteration, `n = 0`. So let's assume that `i < limit` at the beginning, and let's assume that `x` is incremented by a fixed positive quantity `d` in each step.

The inequality you want to solve is then

```
n*(n+1)*d/2 + n*x >= limit - i
```

Solving by the standard methods yields

```
n >= sqrt( (1/2 + x/d)^2 + 2*(limit - i)/d ) - (1/2 + x/d)
```

The smallest `n > 0` with that property is

```
ceiling( sqrt( (1/2 + x/d)^2 + 2*(limit - i)/d ) - (1/2 + x/d) )
```

If all of the quantities can be represented with adequate accuracy as `double`s, that is an O(1) calculation. However, if any of the quantities is large, it is possible that the floating point calculation is a little off. Then you'd have to adjust. For moderately sized quantities, one step will suffice.

But if all the quantities are moderately sized, a binary search is practically also O(1) - the logarithms are bounded and fairly small then - and may well be faster.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I had not realized that it is a quadratic inequality because of the many variables involved. The variables are all 64-bit integers so there may be issues with double precision variables but I'll test it and report success ...